# Rails: join an array with a new line between each component

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, join

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have this method:

```
  def full_address
    [self.first_line, middle_line, last_line, country_name].compact.join("\n")
  end
```

When I try this, it prints a space between components.

I've read several posts on here that say that single quotation marks are the problem (I've also tried those). I also tried:

```
  def full_address
    [self.first_line, middle_line, last_line, country_name].compact.join("<br>")
  end
```

When I try this, it prints 'br' between components.

How do I do this? I've seen responses in several other languages that talk about '+' signs being the solution. I've tried them, it doesnt work. I need help in rails please.

I'm trying to use this in my views show page as:

```
                <%=  @address.full_address %>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have spaces in the components before joining?

Comment: not sure what you mean. it's exactly as above

Comment: which new line you need? br tag or new line (\n)? can you add an expected output?

Comment: @user2860931, I mean that `join` doesn't add magical spaces so I suggest you to doublecheck `first_line` and others if they contain spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
irb(main):004:0> puts ["a", "b", "c", "d"].join("\n")
a
b
c
d
```

You didn't show that part of the code but I suspect that the problem is that you're trying to put the result string in an HTML page. HTML ignores whitespace and that is why you don't get the newlines. You can try the solution you proposed with the `<br>` and try to add `.html_safe`

Comment: that outputs:
sdaf adsf<br>.html_safe asdf adsf asdf<br>.html_safe AUSTRALIA

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error. I meant
`[self.first_line, middle_line, last_line, country_name].compact.join("<br>").html_safe`